# I include the 'time' paramter in my differential equation solver and it messes it up somehow

Tags: r, differential-equations

```
library(deSolve)
require(deSolve)

delta_conc <- function(time, current_state, params) {

  with(as.list(c(current_state, params)),{

    dX <- Y
    dY <- X - X^3 - 0.25*Y + A * sin(t)

    return(list(c(dX, dY)))
  })
}

params <- c(
  A <- 0.2645
)

initial_state <- c(
  X <- 0.9,
  Y <- 0.4
)

times <- 1:10

model <- ode(initial_state, times, delta_conc, params)

summary(model)

matplot(model, type="l",lty=1, main="Enzyme model", xlab="Time")
```

I get this error message when I try to run it:

Error in checkFunc(Func2, times, y, rho) :
The number of derivatives returned by func() (21) must equal the length of the initial conditions vector (2)

When I exclude the 'sin(t)' part it works, so the problem is with that part, but I'm very much a beginner so I have no idea how to approach this problem

Comment: What is `t` in the `sin(t)`? time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should consistently use einer `t` or `time` for the actual time step. In your case `t` is not defined as variable, so `t`is interpreted as transpose-function.

The following should work:

```r
require(deSolve)

delta_conc <- function(time, current_state, params) {
  with(as.list(c(current_state, params)),{
    dX <- Y
    dY <- X - X^3 - 0.25*Y + A * sin(time)
    return(list(c(dX, dY)))
  })
}

params <- c(
  A = 0.2645
)

initial_state <- c(
  X = 0.9,
  Y = 0.4
)

times <- 1:10
model <- ode(initial_state, times, delta_conc, params)
summary(model)

matplot.0D(model, type="l",lty=1, main="Enzyme model", xlab="Time")
```

In addition, the code had also some other issues:

- use either `require` or `library` and not both
- use `=` within `c()`. It is parameter matching and not assignment

Two additional suggestions:

- you can use the deSolve-built in plot function `matplot.0D`
- I would recommend to use `times <- seq(0, 10, length.out = 100)` instead of 1:10. This way the plot will get smooth. Starting time with 1 (or another value) may be ok, but is often more convenient to start time with zero.